# Pakyow app with PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications, pakyow

Can anyone explain how to use a PostgreSQL database with a Pakyow app?

I have built a Pakyow app and I have a PostgreSQL database, but I don't know how to set up the app to use the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pakyow doesn't have database support built-in, but it's compatible with any Ruby ORM (see the [docs](http://pakyow.com/docs/data)). [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) is my go-to library for working with databases in Pakyow. To get Sequel working in your app, you'll first need to add `sequel` and `pg` (since you want to use Postgres) to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sequel'
gem 'pg'
```

Next you'll need to configure the adapter in `app.rb`. The best place to do this is in the `configure` block for each environment. For example, this will configure the adapter for development:

```
$db = Sequel.connect('postgres://user:password@host:port/database_name')
```

You can access the `$db` global throughout your app.

Have a look at the [Sequel Documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/documentation.html) for info about accessing your data via direct queries or models.